# Calling R function within SQL - HANA database

Tags: r, linear-regression, hana

When I call Linear Regression function of R on the data set I get an error message stating

> Could not execute 'CALL ANAGAPPAN.USE_LM("POWER_CONSUMPTION","POWER_CONSUMPTION_OUT") WITH OVERVIEW' in 280 ms 668 µs .  SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34086] Convert data error: Convert Data from R to NewDB failed.;Column 'POWER_APP' not computed from R.

Code is

```
SELECT POWER_APP,POWER_DB,CPUTI,DBTI,DBSU,KBYTES_TRANSFERRED FROM "POWER_CONSUMPTION";
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "POWER_CONSUMPTION_OUT" LIKE "POWER_CONSUMPTION" WITH DATA;
 
DROP PROCEDURE USE_LM;
CREATE PROCEDURE USE_LM(IN train "POWER_CONSUMPTION",OUT result "POWER_CONSUMPTION_OUT")
LANGUAGE RLANG AS
BEGIN
model_app <- lm( POWER_APP ~ CPUTI + DBTI + DBSU + KBYTES_TRANSFERRED, data = train )
PREDICTIVE_ANALYSIS <- predict(model_app)
result <-as.data.frame(PREDICTIVE_ANALYSIS)
END;
 
CALL ANAGAPPAN.USE_LM("POWER_CONSUMPTION","POWER_CONSUMPTION_OUT") WITH OVERVIEW;
SELECT*FROM "POWER_CONSUMPTION";
```

Have gone through the [SAP HANA R Integration Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_r_integration_guide_en.pdf), the example here works. Have checked calling in a standalone Rstudio with the data set it worked too, but when it comes to calling the function of R within SQL to the Rserver it fails.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you also for the edits, really nice of you'll to give me a hand to learn things. Thanks all :) but any thoughts about the code too would be usefull i think!

Comment: check case are tables all in upper case? https://scn.sap.com/thread/3397772  Please don't repeat questions.   If you're not getting the attention you desire use features sucha s bounty.  This  http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answershttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733756/column-store-error-in-hana appears to be a duplicate

Comment: @xQbert: well, i just parted my question as separately from R, Not doing things to get ppl attention, if i thought so, i needed it to have done it like week back itself :), Yes uppercases are being checked and i saw the sap thread earlier too. Thanks for the help.